# deleting items from a list in Python

Tags: python-2.7, list

I am trying to delete the items from a list with this code:

```
lst = [1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1] 
for i in lst:
    lst = lst.remove(i)
    print lst
```

but it gives an error. Could someone help me understand what the problem is?

Comment: What error are you getitng?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that `list.remove` returns `None`, so when you set `lst = lst.remove(i)`, you are replacing `lst` by `None`, so at the next iteration, you will be trying to apply `remove` to `None`, which is not possible. Removing the assignment, you no longer get an error;

```
>>> for i in lst:
...     lst.remove(i)
...     print lst
... 
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
[0, 0, 0, 1]
```

Note that if you iterate over a list while removing in this way, you are effectively skipping over every other element, which is why the loop above would appear to end prematurely:

```
>>> lst = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8] 
>>> for i in lst:
...     lst.remove(i)
...     print(lst)
... 
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
[2, 4, 6, 7, 8]
[2, 4, 6, 8]
```

Comment: You're welcome! If you found the answer useful, you may also want to accept it.

Answer (score 0):

`remove` function is used when you want to remove a specific value from list, not by the index.
If you want to remove an item from list by index use

> lst.pop(i).

[Link to documentation](https://docs.python.org/2.7/tutorial/datastructures.html)